# Are natural daylight lamps for Seasonal Affective Disorder just about the color temperature?

Tags: light

I've seen many expensive lamps made for people who have Seasonal Affective Disorder (SAD) and/or who live in regions where there isn't much daylight during the winter. I'm wondering if the benefit of these lamps is simply the color temperature (typically advertised at 6000K or more), or if there are other aspects of these lights that are meant to be theraputic? Some of these lights are also advertised as "ion therapy lamps".